# font used in this logo?

Tags: fonts

[image]

Any idea what's the font used in this logo?

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is the **Hurme Geometric Sans 3 or 4**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for some font you can always use [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/).
I think it is [Sassoon Infant](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/sassoon/infant/).

Comment: Naa, Sassoon Infant has flat ends on the down stroke of the M